# Convert images which have the same names but different extensions

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, mogrify

For example, I have two files:

```
aaa.jpg        (with cat)
aaa.png        (with dog)
```

As you can see, images are different, despite of their names, which are the same.

I want to convert both these images to one single format.

The basic attempt for this task is

```
mogrify -format jpg *.png
```

But it doesn't work, for obvious reasons (one folder cannot contain multiple files with the same name and extension).

Also, some notes from myself.

1. Please note, this is just example. In real life, it would be about 100-200 images.
2. From my point of view, there seems to exist at least 2 ways to fix this issue: add a timestamp to filename **OR** add random text. I think random text will be better because timestamps sometimes could be equal (if processing is very fast).

So, what do you suggest for this task, and how it could be done? Thanks.

Comment: If your filenames are as undescriptive as `aaa`, you might as well just number your files.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @Andrea Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `mogrify` you can use `convert` modifying the original file name with `-set filename:f`, for example adding a suffix containing a counter:

```
convert *.png -set filename:f "%t_%p" "%[filename:f].jpg"
```

Where the meaning of `%p` and `%t` attributes are:

- **%p**   index of image in current image list
- **%t**   filename without directory or extension (suffix)

More details [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php).

If this is your starting scenario:

```
aaa.jpg        
aaa.png        
bbb.jpg        
bbb.png
```

the final situation would be:

```
aaa.jpg        
aaa.png        
bbb.jpg        
bbb.png   
aaa_0.jpg
bbb_1.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks. I should test it more, but currently copy-pasting code doesn't work. `convert.exe: missing an image filename `0[filename:f].jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3238.`

Comment: This works for me: `convert *.png -set filename:f "%t_%p" "%[filename:f].jpg"`. Why you posted slightly different version? (I mean, why you added "zero" to your command?)

Comment: @jsv Yes, you are right: I made a lot of experiment and I ended up pasting the wrong command... Now I upated the answer, thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 3):

In similar situations I add text (not random) so the files would be aaa_png.png and aaa_jpg.jpg, and therefore after the conversion you'd have aaa_png.jpg and aaa_jpg.jpg which should help you keep track of things and be immune to the problem you had.

As @jsv pointed out, you can do this in one step:

```
convert *.png -set filename:f "%t_%e" "%[filename:f].jpg
```

If you do it this way, the original "aaa.png" and "aaa.jpg" will still exist, along with the new "aaa_png.jpg" file.

Comment: For further readers: `convert *.png -set filename:f "%t_%e" "%[filename:f].jpg"`