# Convert to another folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd, imagemagick, image-manipulation, imagemagick-convert

This command works for me:

```
To run from cmd.exe:
convert *.jpg -set filename:f "%t.%e" "%[filename:f].png"

The same, to run from bat-file (double % instead of single):
convert *.jpg -set filename:f "%%t.%%e" "%%[filename:f].png"
```

Now, let's assume I have this file hierarchy:

```
test\
 |-- small\               <-- this is an empty folder
 |-- image1.jpg
 |-- image2.jpg
```

How I should modify existing script to output files in small folder, as shown below?

```
Current behaviour:
test\
 |-- small\
 |-- image1.jpg
 |-- image2.jpg
 |-- image1.jpg.png
 |-- image2.jpg.png

Desired behaviour:
test\
 |-- small\
      |-- image1.jpg.png
      |-- image2.jpg.png
 |-- image1.jpg
 |-- image2.jpg
```

I tried to use [`%~dp0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/what-does-dp0-mean-and-how-does-it-work), but with no luck currently.

Comment: Try posting the non working script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand, but make a backup before trying:

```
mogrify -path small -format png *.jpg
```

I don't have Windows readily available to test, but in the light of your comments try:

```
convert *.jpg -set filename:f "%%t.%%e" "small/%%[filename:f].png"
```

Comment: Mark, thank you. Currently I'm trying to use `convert` instead of `mogrify` to avoid filename collisions, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44284542/convert-images-which-have-the-same-names-but-different-extensions

Comment: I have updated my answer, please have another look. You may need a backslash on Windows, or a caret (`^`) before the slash.

Comment: Not sure how you could have filename collisions actually, since all your files come from the same directory so they must already be unique.

Comment: Yes, backslash, but doesn't work. I tried similar ways early, with no luck

Comment: I just ran up a Windows XP in VirtualBox and the command exactly as given in my answer works fine...

Comment: Strange, now it works for me too. Probably I made some error while copy-pasting.